# Make webpage available offline using cURL?

Tags: curl, html, offline

Is there any opensource tool built using cURL that downloads a single webpage and makes it available offline?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mulk](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mulk/)

Multi-connection command line tool to download Internet sites. Similar to wget and cURL, but it manages up to 50 parallel links. Main features are: recursive fetching, Metalink retrieving, segmented download and image filtering by width and height.

Or you could use wget if it also suits your needs.